# what is the best way define array cell if it's not defined?

Tags: javascript

I have a 2nd level array, that at a cetain point in the code can be ether undefined or contain value. If it is undefined I need to define it, without giving it any value.
this is what i did:

```
arr[arr2["stripID"]] = typeof(arr[arr2["stripID"]]) === 'undefined' ? [] : arr[arr2["stripID"]];
```

is there a better or shorter way?

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you elaborate on your intent, and maybe factorize `arr2["stripID"]` out of the expression so it gets clearer?

Comment: @IlyaD Additional note: arr2 is an (Object)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects] not an Array :)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr[arr2["stripID"]] = arr[arr2["stripID"]] || [];
```

Should do what you want.

The `||` operator returns the first truthy value in the expression. Because an array is truthy, and the only other value it can be is undefined (falsy), this'll work fine.